# Only allow certain users to check in major versions

Tags: 2010, permissions, check-in

Is it possible to restrict "regular" users to only check in minor versions, while other users, say, approvers etc., can check in major versions?

The backround for my question is that I have a custom workflow that I want to handle publishing of new/new versions of documents. At the same time, I want a "responsible" to be able to unpublish documents. And, as I understand, minor and major versioning must be enabled on a list to be able to use the built-in publish/unpublish functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want sounds exactly like what you get if you check "Yes" for "Require content approval for submitted items" on the library. There's a help link right next to the option in the "Versioning Settings" page.

Comment: Yes, it seems I was looking for problems were there weren't any. Still, thanks to both you and @teylyn :)

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried?

See the Microsoft docu about approval workflows in SharePoint 2010 here:

[Understand approval workflows in SharePoint 2010](http://office.microsoft.com/en-nz/sharepoint-designer-help/understand-approval-workflows-in-sharepoint-2010-HA101857172.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the url. I have one review workflow, and one publishing workflow. The review workflow is started manually by the author. The publishing workflow should start either by clicking a ribbon button, or when clicking "publish major version". What Im trying to do is to make sure that only authorized user can start the publishing workflow, and as a consequence I want only authorized users to be able to check in a major version. Im starting to think I overcomplicate things though. :P